# Shell Script to Archive directories with same name which are older than 2 days

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am new in shell scripting, Trying to write a script to Archive directories with same name at same path which are older than 2 days. Please help

**Example - Log15122023 should be archived like Log15122023.tar.gz**

```
for x in 'find /apps/logs/* -mtime +2'; do
  echo "Tarring $x.."
  tar cvzf $x.tar.gz $x
done
```

---

I am getting below error when i tried executing this script.

Tarring find /apps/logs/* -mtime +2..
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: Google [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and copy/paste all your scripts into http://shellcheck.net while you're learning shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_path="/apps/logs"
find "$dir_path" -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +2 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
    dir_name=$(basename "$dir")
    tar cvzf "${dir_path}/${dir_name}.tar.gz" -C "$dir_path" "$dir_name" && rm -rf "$dir"
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear !! Is it possible to apply this only for the directories created on or after 1 Dec 2023?

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o noglob
IFS=$'\n'; for x in $(find /apps/logs/ -name "*" -mtime +2); do
echo "Tarring $x.."
tar cvzf "${x##*/}.tar.gz" "$x"
done
set +o noglob
```

**for people who came from windows, and never have \n in their filenames and let the filename end with a space**.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'; for x in $(find ...)` is an anti-pattern, do `while IFS= read -r x; do ... done < <(find ...)` instead (use `find ... -print0` and `read -d ''` if supported). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds a serious problem in the code (`for` loop over `find` output).  The report that it produces includes a link to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: are there really people outthere who put \n characters in their filenames or let the filename end with a space??? i changed that

Comment: It is not about `\n` in the filename. In this case, there is a **right way** (using a `while` loop) and a **wrong way** (using a `for` loop.) All the reasonsons that is **wrong** is spelled out in the links provided.